# GetMap not Working

Tags: qgis-server, getmap

I just recently installed QGIS, and I am having trouble getting getmap to work. I could use getcapabilities without too much trouble. However, I could not get getmap to work afterwords. Here is the url that I used.

`http://localhost/qgis/qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&SRS=EPSG:4269&REQUEST=GetMap&map=c:/myprojects/MarionCountyBlight.qgs&BBOX=-36.215710,6.817432,-9.700450,58.551008&WIDTH=500&HEIGHT=1000&LAYERS=MarionCountyBlight&FORMAT=image/png`

I was sure to make sure that the layer and the crs were correct. I also checked ignore getmap and ignore getfeature.

When I used getcapabilities, I noticed a couple of things that seemed a bit off. First, was this line `<BoundingBox CRS="EPSG:3857" maxx="0" minx="0" maxy="0" miny="0"/>` Should the bounding box values all be 0?

Second, when I look at layers, it says the layer name is MarionCountyBlight when that's the name of the project. The layer name should be `tl_2010_18097_tabblock10`, and I'm wondering why QGIS Server can't tell that.

Third, I don't know how to properly restart Apache. I am using Xampp, and I've set the port for that 8080. However, to get to the getcapabilities layer, I can't see why that would the problem though, because I've reloaded both through XAMPP and the Apache-Monitor.

Any ideas on what's wrong and how to fix it?